# i have error in iframe contents html getiing

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to get iframe html but returning undefined why?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://opsukrat.in/iframe.html" id="iframe"></iframe>
    <button onclick="check_html()">Hit me</button>
    <div id="contents">HTML</div>

    <script>
        function check_html() {
            var iframeContents = $('#iframe').contents().find('html').html();
            console.log(iframeContents);
            $('#contents').html('HTML: ' + iframeContents);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

if i am creating file in my server than trying to get than working

`<iframe src="myfile.html" id="iframe"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that by calling `html()` at the end is causing you to try to rewrite the contents of the iframe, and that method returns undefined since rewriting contents onto a tag is expected to return undefined.

You can try :
`var iframeContents = $('#iframe').contents().find('html');`

Or :
`var iframeContents = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;`

Just make sure the page you're calling the iframe from is hosted on the same website, or you might face a cross-origin problem if your website has a [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)